# When did Parvati Devi marry Shiva?

Tags: shiva, bhagavata-purana, parvati, sati-goddess

In the Srimad Bhagavatam, when Sati talks with Shiva about the Daksha Yagya and why she wants to go, she calls Mahadeva, "Shitikantha". This has been translated as Poison-throated one. This **can** refer to the fight of Lord Shiva and Narayana described both in the Mahabharata (Narayaniya section) and the Harivamsa. But there is a possibility that it refers to the Samudra Mathana episode.

When Lord Shiva asks Devi's permission to drink poison, the words used are:

> Sarva Bhuta Suhrt Deva Idam Aaha **Satim** Priyam.

And later on when Sati praises Shiva:

> Praja **Dakshayani** Brahma Vaikunthas Cha Sashamsire.

Furthermore, when Rishi Maitreya concludes his retelling of Dakshayagam, he says,

> Evam Dakshayani hitva Sati Purva kalebaram
>   Jagnye Himavatah Kshetre Menayam Iti **Sushruma**.

The meaning of this verse is: "After giving up the body of Dakshayani, Devi Sati accepted the new body as Himavan's daughter, born from Mena."

The bolded word is Sushruma, which means, "I have heard."
Now, why should a great Rishi like Maitreya "hear" about the birth of Goddess Parvati?

Srila Prabhupada adds "from authoritative sources". So does that mean, Maitreya didn't know himself about the birth of Parvati, or is that just a way of speech?

We also have the story of King Muchukunda, the ancestor of Rama, who fought for long **until Muruga took over.** Which implies Muruga was born later.

So the question is: When exactly was Parvati Devi married to Shiva?

P.S.: There is also an even more confusing theory of mine which I am not sure I can post here. So you can read it [here](http://www.india-forums.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=4166086) (It is where I originally posted the above question, with less response.)

Comment: Shakti actually died in the first Manvantara of the Pitri Kalpa, i.e. the Kalpa before the present Shwetavaraha Kalpa. Parvati was born in the present Vaivasvata Manvantara. Shiva had to live through 21 Manvantaras (not to mention a Pralaya in between!) without his wife at his side. see comments of [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/3500) answer.

Comment: I don't put my trust on that. It could be an erratic translation. But anyways, does that make Parvati the youngest goddess?

Comment: @TheDestroyer can you help me understand this - the text says Sati was born in the 1st Manvantar of the Pitri Kalpa which was the 30th Kalpa in the second Parardha of Brahma. Parvati was born in the Vaivasvat i.e. 7th Manvantar of the present Varah Kalpa. So is the present Varah Kalpa the 31st one?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Different Puranas mention different number for Sweta Varaha Kalpa. Rudra stayed without Shakti for 21 Manvantars (1.5 Kalpa of time) as per Skanda Purana. But i think other Puranas say differently. I think we need to analyze this considring Kalpa Bheda. We can this discuss this in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy), if you are interested.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what Shiva tells Parvati in [this excerpt](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27478/62f_chapter_19_2.pdf#toolbar=0&pagemode=none&view=FitBH&page=1%22) from the Prabhasa Khanda of the Skanda Purana:

> In this Varaha Kalpa, O goddess, you became Parvati obtained by Himavan through his penance, **when the Chakshusha Manvantara has passed off**.  O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Daksha you had to be separated from me for the duration of a day of Brahma.  Your span of life is the period of his six months.

It says "when the Chakshusha Manvantara has passed off", so she was either born close to the end of the Chakshusha Manvantara or the beginning of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  And yes, that does make her one of the youngest of the major gods we worship now.

Comment: What is the statement "Your span of life is the period of his six months."? Whose six months. Span of which life? And how was Daksha's anger so powerful that it could separate Shakti from Shiva (for a Kalpa)?

Comment: And so the most youngest one becomes Muruga? (Discounting the avataras.)

Comment: @Surya Shiva is saying that Parvati will have a span of life of 6 months of Brahma, i.e. a little over 2000 Kalpas. And I think that what Shiva is saying is that it's because of Daksha's anger (toward Shiva) that Shakti died, and as a result of Shakti's death they were separated for a Kalpa.

Comment: @Surya And yeah, the youngest god (out of the major ones commonly worshipped now) would be either Muruga or Ganesha, depending on your beliefs about which one of them is older and which is younger :-)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Does that mean Goddess Parvathi die? What about story of Shiva telling about  his immortality? Parvathi is said to got boon of immortality after Shiva saying his **"Amarkadha"**.  This is the legend of [Amarnath Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarnath_Temple)

Comment: @Keshav TBH, all this Kalpa thing is really muddled up.

Comment: @AnilKumar Logically speaking, Parvati Devi does not 'die'. But from Sri Vaishnava perspective (which is Keshav's perspective) she is also a jivatma, and therefore will give up her present body and don a new form.

Comment: @Surya Forget my Sri Vaishnava perspective, I'm quoting the Prabhasa Khanda of the Skanda Purana.  From a Shaivite perspective, the supreme Shiva and Adi Parashakti are eternal, but their manifestations Rudra and Parvati are not eternal; those are created beings that have a birth and they will eventually cease to exist, and then they will be created anew.  It's similar to how Sri Vaishnavas believe that Para Vasudeva, the supreme Vishnu, is eternal, but Vyuha Vasudeva, the Vishnu who dwells in the ocean of milk, is a created being who will one day cease to exist, and then be created again.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What will happen to Ganesh and Kartikeya then? They will also die and take the same form again?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yeah, any created being must ultimately cease to exist, sooner or later.

Comment: @Keshav If she lives for six months, then what of the Sati of the next Kalpa?

Answer (score 7):

1) **Why is the name Sitikantha used?**
 
Sitikantha is an eternal name of Lord Shiva because it is stated in Vedas. Vedas clearly call Lord Shiva as "**Sitikanthaya Cha**". And Vedas were before Samundra Manthan and also before fight of Shiva and Narayana (as told in Narayania). So, Sitikantha can mean whose throat is white due to using of ash in neck. And more importantly Sitikantha name is used in just beginning part of 5th Anuvaka of Sri Rudram (YajurVeda) where all specific names are used. The names from Bhava to Vyuptakesha are Specific names of Lord Shiva. They are used for other Gods only for the sake of completing Sahasranaamas. And Sitikantha name also exists between the specific name. So it is clear it is specific name.

> नमो भवाय च रुद्राय च। नमश्शर्वाय च पशुपतये च। 
>   नमो नीलग्रीवाय च **शितिकण्ठाय च**। नमः कपर्दिने च व्युप्तकेशाय च। नमस्सहस्राक्षाय च शतधन्वने च। नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च। (YajurVeda 4.5.1)
>   
>   Salutations to Him who is the source of all things (**Bhava**). And to Him who is the remover of all cries (**Rudra**). Salutations to the destroyer (**Sarva**) and to the protector of all beings in bondage (**Pasupati**). Salutations to Him whose throat is blue (**Nilagriva**) and whose throat is also white (**Sitikantha**). Salutations to Him of the matted locks (**Kapardin**), and to Him who is clean-shaven (**Vyuptakesha**). Salutations to Him who has a Thousand eyes and a hundred bows. Salutations to Him who dwells on the mount and who is in the form of Shipivista.

So, Sitikantha name can be used irrespective of any events.
2) Your other questions can be answered from the fact that Lord Shiva is married to Sati and Parvati multiple times as I discuss in my [**answer here.**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868)

> केचद्वदन्ति तां ज्येष्ठां मध्यमां चापरे शिवाम् ।
>   सर्वानन्तरजां केचित्कल्पभेदात्त्रयं च सत् ।।
>   
>   **Some say that Shivă (Sati) was eldest of them all, some say she was middle one and some wise trear her as youngest of all. All three opinions are correct, because of difference of Kalpa.**

**And Parvati who was present during Sumbha Nisumbha Vadh is not same Parvati present today.** She became Sati in Pitri Kalpa (previous kalpa) and again Parvati in Present kalpa and again married to Lord Shiva. I have explained it in detail in the [same answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868)

So there are many Parvati and many Sati. Bhagvatam may be narrating event of any time among those many. So we need not to be surprised seeing the word Satipriya, Dakshyaani etc..

Even if we consider Bhagvatam is describing churning of ocean of Present Chakshusa Manvantara when Sati had already died and still why Sati priya, Dakshyaani words are used? We can solve it in this way:

When Devas go in refugee of Lord Shiva in S.B. 8.7.19 the words used are:

> "arakṣyamāṇāḥ **śaraṇaṁ sadāśivam** "
>   Feeling unsheltered and very much afraid, they sought shelter of SadaShiva.

It uses the word **Saranam SadaSivam** ie. Refugee of SadaShiva.

So, Devas may actually have gone to that place where SadaShiva lives (not where Sri Parvati Pati lives).

Also the terms like "ParaBrahman", "Paramatma", "Bhutatma Bhuta Bhawana", "Ishworo Bandha Mokshoyo" etc.. are used which applies to SadaShiva rather than Sri Parvati Pati as he has birth through forehead of Brahma (although it may also be used for him).

And most importantly S.B. 8.7.29 states:

> "O lord, the five important Vedic mantras are **represented by your five faces,** from which the thirty-eight most celebrated Vedic mantras have been generated. Your Lordship, being celebrated as Lord Śiva, is self-illuminated. You are directly situated as the supreme truth, known as Paramātmā."

Five face is the representation of SadaShiva. So it is likely that Devas are in front of SadaShiva. Sada Shiva is always with his consort Amba as represented collectively by the term Samba SadaShiva.

So the term Sati Priya, Dakshyaani may be used just as epithets only just as names of Lord Krishna are also used to glorify Lord Vishnu, In the same way Sri Parvati Pati is direct incarnation of Sri SadaShiva. So he can be denoted by using epithets or names of Sri ParvatiPati.

As there are many Parvati we can't answer when did Lord Shiva married Sri Parvati? However we can tell when did he married with Latest Parvati (who is incarnation of previous Parvati and Sati).

And as answered already from the Prabhasa Khanda of the Skanda Purana:

> In this Varaha Kalpa, O goddess, you became Parvati obtained by Himavan through his penance, **when the Chakshusha Manvantara has passed off.** O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Daksha you had to be separated from me for the duration of a day of Brahma. Your span of life is the period of his six months.

So, she was either born close to the end of the Chakshusha Manvantara or the beginning of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.

However this doesn't make Sri Parvati youngest of the Gods we worship now. It is because there were many Parvati in past age before the birth of Present Parvati.

Comment: Where does Sadashiva reside? Rudra is present inside Hiranyagarbha and Maha Shambhu outside Hiranyagarbha so where is Sadashiva? Or it might be possible that he appears in a combined form of Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Maha Shambhu, <who is the last one?>.

Comment: Nicely reasoned. :)

Comment: @Chinmay Sadashiva is the same as Mahashambhu who is present outside the Brahmanda(s) in Shivaloka/Manidvipa.