# Reflection of "Yada yada hi dharmasya..." in Durga Saptashati?

Tags: scripture, history, durga, goddess, devi

Bhagvad Gita is a 701 versed text which is inside Mahabharata. And similarly Durga Saptashati (**Sapta =7 and Shat =100**) is also 7×100= 700 versed text which is inside Markandeya Purana which is also known as Devi Mahatmya.

One of the most famous and important verse in Bhagvad Gita is  Bhagvad Gita Chapter 4 Verse 7, where Lord states to Arjuna as:

> **यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत |
>
>   अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम् ||** 7||
>  
>   Whenever and wherever there is a decline in righteousness and an increase in unrighteousness, O Arjuna, at that time I manifest myself.

As Devi Mahatmya is also related to destruction of demonic forces by Devi, **are there similar statements made by Devi in Durga Saptashati ?**

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thanks for this question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, In **chapter 91** of Markandeya Purana (or **chapter 11 of Saptashati**), Devi speaks about her various coming incarnations in future to destroy demonic forces. In the last verse or verse 55, [**Devi states:**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868)

> **इत्थं यदा यदा बाधा दानवोत्था भविष्यति ॥
>
>   तदा तदावतीर्याहं करिष्याम्यरिसंक्षयम्** ॥५५॥
>  
>   Whenever and wherever there will be disturbances from the demonic forces, then I shall incarnate myself and destroy them all.

Comment: Nice find mate ..This only confirms the oneness of all Gods

Comment: (1/3) Nice find! However, IMO the primary similarity is actually of words *"yada yada, ... tada..."*. Here is my take: In Gita, the manifestation of "[supreme] self" (*Atma*, not Krishna) happens. Now this *Atma* itself is ultimately responsible for *Dharma* & *Adharma* as it pervades everywhere. On the contrary in Saptashati, the *Devi* (goddess) does the destruction in her personal form. May be the personal form might be manifesting in other forms. The major difference is about "Destruction of *DAnava*-s". The ***DAnava*-s are said to be children of Kashyap through his wife *Danu*.**

Comment: (2/3) Hence, killing *DAnava-s* is more like destroying certain group of people. For example, "killing Nazis" or "killing xyz ethnics". This quite specific compared to the very general correction of *Dharma* vs *Adharma*. Also as a side note, I couldn't locate "incarnate" in the Sanskrit verse. May be I have missed somewhere. Anyways, "I get created" from Gita is actually quite explicit. BTW, this comment is not to refute this verse. But just my view that, both verse are "probably" not similar. Thanks to BR Chopra, "Yada yada" & "Karmanye vAdhika" are the most popular verses.

Comment: (3/3) Now there is something, completely unrelated to your Q&A. I feel that "Yada Yada..." is probably 1 of the most, over-amplified verse from Gita due to amazingly sung by Mahendra Kapoor in BR Chopra's MahAbhArata. In my personal view, its meaning should be very simple. Whenever there is a drought(adharma), I become rain(dharma); Whenever there is war(adharma), I become peace(dharma); whenever there is merrymaking(adharma), I become sadness(dharma), whenever there is wastage(adharma), I become scarcity(dharma)... & so on. Also, the "yuge yuge" (4.8) time differs from context to context.

Comment: There Devi says: "I again shall assume a dreadful form on the mountain Himachala, and devour the giants **to protect the sages:** all the ascetics will bow and applaud me. I shall be called Bhima-Devi, when Aruna shall disturb the three world; then I shall turn a roving beettle. I will destroy the great giant **for the advantage of these three worlds:** all will applaud me by the name of Bramhani in the world. **Whenever disturbances shall arise from the demonic forces, then I shall incarnate and destroy the enemies."**

Comment: @iammilind 2) and why do you think in Gita it is Atman/Brahman/Self is speaking and it is not possible in Other places like Saptashati... as all Name-Forms are illusions (in Advaita) statements made by Devi are also statements of Nirguna Brahman (in Advaita)... for eg. In chapter of destruction of Sumbha Devi speaks:          .."देव्युवाच॥४॥
**एकैवाहं जगत्यत्र द्वितीया का ममापरा।**"  "I am everything in this whole world, there is no second besides me."...

Comment: *"you wouldn't conclude that there Danava means demonic forces & not childrens of Danu"* -- It's exactly opposite from what I say. I say, "DAnava = Children of Kashyapa through his wife Danu". Analogically, like how Kaurava-s are to GAndhari, DAnava-s are to Danu. Some might be good, many might be bad. But it's still a specific race. Not generalized. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46568/discussion-between-iammilind-and-tezz).