# Whose marriage happened first, Lord Shiva's or Lord Vishnu's?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, marriage

Whose marriage happened first, Lord Shiva's or Lord Vishnu's? I heard that one of them supported the concept of marriage first. Who?

Comment: Neither if we consider cyclic nature of time.

Comment: As I discuss in my answer here.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868 Lord Shiva married with many Sati and many Parvati..

Comment: This is different question.

Comment: This is an interesting question, really don't know the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me say the answer first.
It is **Lord Shiva**.

Two basic facts support the answer.

**1)** **Lord Vishnu's** wife **Devi Laxmi** was one of the ratna(Gem) who was produced from the Samudra(Ocean) during the Samudra manthan(**Sanskrit:** समुद्रमन्थन, **lit**. churning of the ocean). And then she accepted Vishnu as her eternal consort.

**2)** And the second one is, **The Samudra Manthan** process released a number of things from the Ocean. One of them was **Halahala** ,a deadly poison.This terrified all the creature who participated in that process because the poison  could destroy all of them. Then the gods approached **Lord Shiva** for protection. **Shiva** consumed the poison in an act to protect the universe, and his consort, **Devi Parvati**, grabbed Shiva's throat in an effort to prevent the most deadly poison from affecting the universes inside Lord Shiva. As a result, Shiva's throat turned **blue**.

So we can conclude that **Devi Parvati**,the wife of Lord Shiva was already there when **Devi Laxmi**  came out as a **Ratna(gem)**.

Which implies **Lord Shiva's** marriage happened first

**Source:-**

1) [Wikipedia link of Samudra Manthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan)

2)**The Bhagavata Purana**

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Wikipedia is not recommended source for this site. Can you also mention exact chapter of Bhagavata Purana?

Comment: There was Lakshmi Devi even before Samudra Manthan too. There are other births of Lakshmi also. It is due to the curse of Sage Durvasa, the churning of the ocean happened. There was Lakshmi at the time of DakshaYajna also. So, we can't say that Shiva's marriage happened first.

Comment: This Wikipedia analogy is completely WRONG. Goddess Lakshmi was actually daughter of Bhrigu & Khyati earlier and got married to Lord Vishnu. Indra showed disrespect to her (or sage Durvasa in some stories), she made her abode in the abysmal depth of the sea and later emerged during Samudra Manthan. Read in more detail about other incarnations of Goddess Lakshmi from http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp042.htm