# Are there any incarnations of adi shakti between sati and parvati?

Tags: shiva

According to one story Shiva wears the munda mala which contains 108 skulls of previous incarnations of parvati . How many incarnations of adi shakti are there after parvati ?

Comment: There are cycles of Sati and Parvati and their incarnations are also infinite: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868

Comment: It seems that story in which Shiva 'wears the munda mala which contains 108 skulls of previous incarnations of parvati' is interpolated. As per most of the stories Shiva was too much attached with Sati's body (almost burnt) and started wondering with that. Later, parts of this body fell down (naturally or as per few stories by Sudarshana Chakra) on 108 places on Earth known as Shakti Pīṭhaṃ. Out of 108 Shakti Pīṭhaṃ, 18 are known as Maha Shakti Pīṭhaṃ...

Comment: In question title, you are asking about incarnations between Sati and Parvati but in the question body, you are asking about incarnations after Parvati, what is your main question?

Comment: @DebasritaSaha If you have created a new account, then merge them. Read [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Please register and don't create multiple accounts.