# Will Adi shakti be born again in the near future or has been born in past ? If yes ,then when ? What do we know about these incarnations?

Tags: shiva, karma, parvati

Adi Shakti is Prakriti herself, so she dies. But she takes rebirths to unite with Shiva again and again.

So my questions are:

Will Adi Shakti be born again in the near future or has been born in past? If yes , then when ? What do we know about these incarnations?

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question 'Title' in "body" of question? This is Q&A site. You should answer the question with proper sources. Visit [tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). For answering, visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: Adi Shakti is not Prakriti.. because She is Parasamvit the Supreme Consciousness whereas Parkriti is something Jada or inert.. Adi Shakti is the Mother of everything including Prakriti..you can say that.. and Goddess Parvati is the born form of the same Adi Parashakti..

Comment: The question seems to be clear and answerable now.. so casting the reopen vote.. you can alter anything if needed.

Comment: It is not clear if the OP wanted to know the whether she will incarnate or asking the question in the title and answering the question in the body. **It is still unclear** and the OP should modify it. Hence not reopenable. Leaving closed till the OP modifies and edits the question.

Comment: Devi Adi MahaShakti is never born or dies. She is eternal and has no beginning, and end.

Answer (score 7):

As I discuss in my [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868) there were and there will be several incarnations of Devi:

> देव्युवाच॥४०॥
> वैवस्वतेऽन्तरे प्राप्ते अष्टाविंशतिमे युगे।
> शुम्भो निशुम्भश्‍चैवान्यावुत्पत्स्येते महासुरौ॥४१॥
> नन्दगोपगृहे जाता यशोदागर्भसम्भवा।
> ततस्तौ नाशयिष्यामि विन्ध्याचलनिवासिनी॥४२॥
>
> Devi said, **on the twenty-eighth age of Vaivasvata, Sumbha, and Nisumbha, shall be regenerated. I shall reside on the mountain of Vindhya, I shall be born in the race of cowherds in the womb of Yasoda, and destroy them.**

And after it:

> रक्षांसि भक्षयिष्यामि मुनीनां त्राणकारणात्।
> तदा मां मुनयः सर्वे स्तोष्यन्त्यानम्रमूर्तयः॥५१॥
> भीमा देवीति विख्यातं तन्मे नाम भविष्यति।
> यदारुणाख्यस्त्रैलोक्ये महाबाधां करिष्यति॥५२॥
> तदाहं भ्रामरं रूपं कृत्वाऽसंख्येयषट्‌पदम्।
> त्रैलोक्यस्य हितार्थाय वधिष्यामि महासुरम्॥५३॥
> भ्रामरीति च मां लोकास्तदा स्तोष्यन्ति सर्वतः।
> इत्थं यदा यदा बाधा दानवोत्था भविष्यति॥५४॥
> तदा तदावतीर्याहं करिष्याम्यरिसंक्षयम् ॥५५॥
>
> I again shall assume a dreadful form on the mountain Himachala, and devour the giants to protect the sages: all the ascetics will bow and applaud me. **I shall be called Bhima-Devi, when Aruna shall disturb the three world;** then I shall turn a roving beettle. I will destroy the great giant for the advantage of these three worlds: all will applaud me by the name of Bhramari in the world. **Whenever disturbances shall arise from the demonic forces, then I shall incarnate and destroy the enemies.**

Source of above verses are Devi Mahatmya of Markandeya Purana.