# How does Mother Parvati change Her form to Mother Sati?

Tags: devi, sati-goddess

As per the answer to the question :  [Wouldn't most of the incarnations of Devi be of Sati, not Parvati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati)

> Thus after six months of Brahma, present Parvati also leaves her body and then after certain time she is again born and Lord Shiva marries her again and again and again. So the cycle continues.

So it seems that the Mother Goddess takes two alternative forms Sati and Parvati for being consort of Lord Shiva. Sati leaves Her body at the Daksha-yajna. How and when does Parvati leave Her body to be born again as Sati?

Please cite proper sources.

Comment: Sati reincarnated as Parvati.

Comment: Isnt Amarnath cave a place where Shiva imparts immortality knowledge to Parvati?

Comment: @AkshayS Yes, but She slept.And otherwise how would She reincarnate as Sati?

Comment: your q is invalid.

Comment: @Lakhi thank you:)