# Why people worship shiv-ling?

Tags: shiva-lingam

'Shiva linga' is  a form , a symbol of our origin. Form is tangible and objective, thought is intangible and subjective.
"When 'linga' meets with 'yoni'  we come in this universe, we born ,  we incarnate,  it's a symbol, how we came in existence, how we originated." If linga and yoni doesn't meet we never born.

Someone give me the reason to worship it. It creates more questions:

- So how the first man and women come to existence?
- And what is the role of GOD if we need to worship to our body parts?

Comment: Because Shiva got cursed by Maharishi Bhrigu that He will only be worshiped in linga form, not his body form. For more detail read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19251/if-shiva-linga-is-worshiped-in-all-yugas-then-what-curse-did-rishi-bhrigu-give-t/19253#19253).

Comment: You worship your body parts? We don't.

Comment: Linga is not body part of any human. Linga is mark or symbol of Parabrahman.

Comment: @Rishabh Shiva got cursed? God can be cursed, what is the logic of God in Hinduism, ask a question which opens more doubts

Comment: @Rickross: Just comment without understand anything, I try to understand the concept but you fall down to personal comments. Do a deep research of it and then comment.

Comment: @AliAdravi There is nothing doubtful about God can be cursed if you ever understand the God properly. Thing is, God loves their devotee so much and whatever their true devotee wish for, God fullfil that wish without delay. Maharishi Bhrigu is a great great great devotee of Shiva. When Bhrigu gave cursed then Shiva accept it with all his heart coz it was his true devotee's wish which he did fulfill by carrying that curse. Shiva can't be effected by any curse but if his true devotee put curse then Shiva accept it coz he never rejects any kind of offering from true devotees even if it is a curse.

Answer (score 1):

No one *knows for sure* how life began.

Scientifically speaking it has been reasoned that very primitive forms of life like amoeba originated and  gradually became organized, became more complex evolving into life forms that evolved in stages like a fish, an animal and man in several avatars with increased function of mind action over the body. Darwin has a popular theory of evolution based on competition,survival and adaptation.

Males and females of every species know well how they can initiate life but know almost nothing beyond that.. The male earns or hunts food and provides protection against the elements, the female cares until the young acquire their own capacity to care for themselves.In no other way they know how by artificial means can new life be created or controlled.

Spiritually it is believed in many faiths that life is given in and taken out by a Superior composite form that is *structured both ways*, integrated in all living entities and at the same time contained within every life form.This spiritual awareness varies across all life forms in many cultures.

Worship of Shiv-Ling including yoni form is a Bhakthi addressal to the Superior form contained in us about the mysterious cyclic process of creation,sustenance and eventual amalgamation with myriad individual and social group connections.

It is not worship of the likeness of our own body parts meant for duplication.It is the nature of connection to the Supernatural regarding Adwaithic identity designed to removes ego-centrality. Main difficulty is due to extreme  variance in modes of dependence to God manifested in such vagueness and awareness amongst us.

Comment: Bro you are telling me the biology. I asked about the reason of worship of Linga. Is there any proof in Linga Veda?  Otherwise we need to worship the Amoiba, fishes, animals etc.

Comment: @AliAdravi What Amoiba, fishes and animals will give on in return of your worship?

Comment: Neither worshiping fishes, animals will give anything nor the Linga. Only our Lord the creator gives us.

Comment: @AliAdravi What do u mean by "nor the Linga". Linga is the formless (bodyless) shiva. And shiva is the Lord. Shiva first appear as energy pillar and that energy pillar has become the symbol of shiva which we knows as Shivlinga. Shiva linga word has come from Sanskrit where Shiva means "Lord Shiva" And Linga means "Symbol/Mark". HENCE Shiv Linga means "Symbol Of Shiva". Means Symbol of Lord.

Comment: @Rishabh: Ling means Mark then what is the meaning of YONI which is the part of ShivLing. Everyone know LING & YONI is the male and female sexual parts. If linga is formess then what this form is which people worship?

Comment: @AliAdravi Dude... Do yourself a favor and Search on google.... Type these  "Meaning Of shivling". You will find thousands of articles that will tell you linga  meas Mark/symbol. If you know how to browse google then search, else let me know I will teach you how to search google to find your Answer. If you don't trust us then go and find on google by yourself.

Comment: @AliAdravi Have you seen the chinese Yin-Yang two dimensional depiction? You are seeing here an advanced Indian/Hindu three dimensional depiction. The man, the woman, the Supreme are united in a functional combination for Creation that may have got obscured by centuries of tolerance and accommodation to all viewpoints.

Comment: @Rishabh: Thanks for teaching me the way to search google. I am a Sr. Soft. Eng, I can speak Sanskrit  because I study in rural area of UP in PATHSHALA, I don't have any reason to fight with you. Thanks for all your comments

Comment: @AliAdravi If you know how to search on google then Make search regarding meaning of Shiva linga AND Please don't spread fake roumors that linga means any body part. Search google and find truth by yourself if you don't believe us.

Comment: @AliAdravi  in his book ( I forget title ) Nirad Chaudhuri gave an explanation  so that people do get to other meanings. Ancient religion and old  concepts  have to grapple with changing modern or revised thoughts. But all have their own place.

Comment: @Rishabh: Could you please tell me the Sanskrit of Men and Women sexual part? I am not spreading fake rumors, Let me know if you can get something different than Ling and Yoni. http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0+&tinput=yoni&trans=Translate try this link

Comment: @AliAdravi Many words are there that contains more than one meanings. Haven't you ever seen any word that has more than one meaning...? If not, then my friend you must be born few days ago. You can find real meaning of Shiva Linga word in this site in many posts. Moderator himself told you in comment section that LInga is not body part of someone. And google also telling you the same And if still you don't wanna accept the truth then this implies one thing that You has some mean purpose, thats why u don't wanna listen to any proof.