# Why does Canto 4, Chapter 2 of Bhagavata Purana insult Shiva devotees?

Tags: shiva, bhagavata-purana

> [SB 4.2.28](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/2/28) — One who takes a vow to satisfy Lord Śiva or who follows
>   such principles will certainly become an atheist and be diverted from
>   transcendental scriptural injunctions.

Also in next verse;

> [SB 4.2.29](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/2/29) — Those who vow to worship Lord Śiva are so foolish that
>   they imitate him by keeping long hair on their heads. When initiated
>   into worship of Lord Śiva, they prefer to live on wine, flesh and
>   other such things.

Comment: Do you ask questions for sake of asking? Can't you read before line that it was just Brigus curse? Why do you say Bhagavata Purana?

Comment: @TheDestroyer so it is only from the point of view of sage as per your answer.

Comment: @Hindu possible interpolations from non shaiva sects...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, are you saying that this verse is not in the Bhagavata Purana i.e. it was added/interpolated later, or that its meaning is distorted ?

Answer (score 15):

Bhagavata Purana has nothing to do here.  It was **Brigu** who spoke those words. Even Daksha cursed Shiva out of arrogance and ignorance. First Daksha cursed Shiva, as Shiva didn't stand when he came to hall and Nandi cursed Daksha and other Brahmanas. Brigu cursed Shiva and his devotees as a counter curse to Nandi's curse.

Brigu is known for arrogance as he also kicked Vishnu on His chest in Vaikunta.

Let's see before verse. **SB 4.2.27** (translated by GV Tagore)

> तस्यैवं वदतः शापं श्रुत्वा द्विज-कुलाय वै भृगुः प्रत्यसृजच् छापं
>   ब्रह्म-दण्डं दुरत्ययम्
>
> Hearing him pronounce this curse upon the Brähmana community ( as a
>   whole ) , Bhrgu uttered a counter-curse which is an irrevocable
>   punishment inflicted by Brahmanical power.

Also see how GV Tagore translated those verses of Brigu's curse.

> 28. ' 'Those who observe the vows to propitiate god Siva,  and those that follow them, shall be the heretics and the  opponents of true
>       Sästras.
> 29. They shall lose their (sense of) purity, shall be dullwitted. Thcy shall wear matted locks of hair and bones, and smear themselves with
>       ashes. They shall enter the cult of Siva  worship where winc shall be
>       the divinity.

These are words of Brigu Rishi not words of Vyasa or Vishnu to take as granted. Even Rshis got deluded many times.  As described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19321),  without will of Shiva, no sage can curse Shiva. Many sages and Devas in Daksha Yajna were deluded by [Uma's Maya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16778/did-the-destruction-of-dakshas-sacrifice-also-happen-in-present-vaivasvata-manv/16779#16779).

Later Shiva and His gaNAs punished all sages and Devas.

**SB 4.5.19** says (translated by GV Tagore)

> जुह्वतः स्रुव-हस्तस्य श्मश्रूणि **भगवान् भवः** भृगोर् लुलुञ्चे सदसि यो
>   ’हसच् छ्मश्रु दर्शयन्
>
> Glorious **Virabhadra** pulled out mustaches and the  beard of Bhrgu,
>   while he was offering the oblations with *sruva*  (a ladle) in his hand,
>   as he had laughed derisively in the as-  sembly showing his beard
>   (when Daksa insulted Siva).

**Chapter 37  Rudra Samhita of Shiva Purana** also says the same.

Regarding words of Brigu on wine, it looks like they are alluding to esoteric and subtle Vamachara practices as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/how-is-tantric-sex-meat-eating-and-alcohol-consumption-justified/19013#19013).

Comment: are you saying this verse is not in the Bhagavata Purana i.e. it was added/interpolated later, or that the meaning is distorted ?

Comment: @ram I am not sure whether it was interpolated or not personally and i didn't say it was interpolated in answer. I said meaning **could** be distorted.

Comment: Not happy to see great rishis shown in bad light by some puranas.