# Are ALL devotees of Lord Shiva cursed by Rishi Bhrigu to follow anti-Vedic principles?

Tags: shiva, bhagavata-purana, bhrigu

Srimad Bhagavatam 4.2.28 & 4.2.29 states:

> *bhava-vrata-dharā ye ca
>   ye ca tān samanuvratāḥ
>   pāṣaṇḍinas te bhavantu
>   sac-chāstra-paripanthinaḥ*
>
> **English Translation**: Those who observe the vows to propitiate god Siva, and those that follow them, shall be the heretics and the opponents of true scriptures. (SB 4.2.28)
>
> *naṣṭa-śaucā mūḍha-dhiyo jaṭā-bhasmāsthi-dhāriṇaḥ viśantu śiva-dīkṣāyāṁ yatra daivaṁ surāsavam*
>
> They shall lose their sense of purity, shall be dullwitted. They shall wear matted locks of hair and bones, and smear themselves with ashes. They shall enter the cult of Siva worship where wine shall be the divinity. (S.B. 4.2.29)

Does this mean that **ALL** Shaivites are cursed to follow anti-Vedic principles? Apologies to anyone including to Lord Shiva, offended by my question.

Comment: This sounds very much like a Vaishnava interpolation. It is not true that devotees of Shiva become atheists. Shiva is worshipped vedically with namakam, camakam , rudram etc. Shiva gives gnyAna which is essential to mOkSa. Counter your Q with the fact that the result of devotion to Shiva is devotion to Vishnu and vice versa.

Comment: See [Why does Canto 4, Chapter 2 of Bhagavata Purana insult Shiva devotees?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19484/3500)

Comment: compare/contrast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, Bhrigu's curse is not applicable to all devotees of Shiva. It is only applicable to those who worship Lord Shiva as different from or superior to Lord Vishnu:

> After bathing in Bindu-Sarovara and taking darshana of Sri Bhuvaneshvara, the all-
>   opulent Lord, Sri Krishna Chaitanya sat contentedly, wholly immersed in the bliss of prema. Mahaprabhu then ate choice foods prepared by the bhaktas, and afterwards as He 
>   rested contentedly, He contemplated the lotus feet of Sri Krishna.
>
> The illustrious Lord thought, "If somehow the maha-prasadam of the trident-wielding god of gods could be obtained, then we could truly take pleasure." As He was reflecting thus, a certain Brahmana came before Him, bearing in his 
>   hands a small portion of Mahadeva's prasadam.
>
> He said, "Please accept this prasadam of Mahadeva." Hearing this, Lord Gaura at 
>   once stood up and accepted the prasadam with bowed head. They all gathered together around the maha-prasadam, and the Lord honored it with 
>   His servants as though it were immortal nectar. Thus Gaura Hari showed how dear 
>   Shiva is to Lord Krishna. Again Gaura Hari arose very early in grat happiness, and after bathing quickly in 
>   Bindu-Sarovara, He bowed before Lord Shiva and then left on His way.
>
> When the powerful brahmana Sri Damodara Pandita heard that the Lord had eaten the remnants of Shiva's food, He said, "One should not eat the remnants of Lord Shiva because Bhrigu Muni has placed a 
>   curse on those who worship him. Why then did the all-opulent transcendental Lord, 
>   knowing this, eat that food?"
>
> Hearing this, Murari replied to the noble vipra, "Hear from me the reason for 
>   which the Lord ate those nectarean remnants of Lord Shiva."
>
> When Sri Krishna Chaitanya made His auspicious arrival, Mahadeva joyously accepted 
>   Him as an honored guest. Please hear somewhat further. **When bhaktas worship Mahadeva thinking of him as the best among Vaishnavas, 
>   Maheshvara accepts that offering from them, and that food should be considered great 
>   and pure prasadam.
>   Those who in a sectarian spirit differentiate between Sri Krishna and his bhaktas 
>   indeed fall down. Sri Hari personally advented in the form of a bhakta as Chaitanya 
>   Mahaprabhu in order to instruct such inimical persons.** The Lord of all gods, who is the supreme controller of the cosmic manifestation, 
>   certainly seeks to benefit all embodied beings. Thus, by His reverential acceptance 
>   of Lord Shiva's food-remnants, He teaches them by His example. **Wherever the lingam is established and worshipped with a conception that Lord Shiva 
>   and Sri Hari have separate parties, there Bhrigu's curse will act, because of this 
>   offense of a dualistic concept. Hari and Sankara have one interest. If in the presence of a Shiva liìgam someone 
>   worships Them without a dualistic concept, the curse will not have effect. By people understand Their unity of interest, love will increase for both Hari and 
>   Shankara, and worship for Them both will increase. By tasting such maha-prasadam one can attain liberation, be cured from terrible 
>   diseases, and obtain undisturbed prosperity. Those who out of delusion do not eat such maha-prasadam become offenders to both 
>   Hari and Shiva. They become diseased and bereft of opulence.**
>   Wherever the beginningless lingam of Lord Shiva is worshipped with great respect by Vaishnavas in order to develop love for Shri Krishna, there will be no doubt about 
>   accepting the remnants of Lord Shiva's food. O vipra, such devotional service is verily auspicious for all embodied beings.
>
> **(From *Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitra Mahakavyam*, Canto 3, Sarga 9)**

So basically one should worship Lord Shiva keeping in mind that He's non-different from Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Nowhere is Lord Shiva equated with Lord Vishnu in the above passage. "When bhaktas worship Mahadeva thinking of him as the best among Vaishnavas, Maheshvara accepts that offering from them, and that food should be considered great and pure prasadam. Those who in a sectarian spirit differentiate between Sri Krishna and his bhaktas indeed fall down." What is condemned is offending Lord Shiva since he is devotee of Lord Vishnu, but not equated to Lord Vishnu here.

Answer (score 9):

It appears that the interpretation of the shloka of 4th Canto is not correct.  actually Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana has at no space criticised Lord Shiva or shaivism.  On the other hand, in the sankalpa for reading of Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana the prayer clearly states - Vaishnavas please state "Dasoham Tava Keshava" while Smartas (Shaivites) state "Soham Tava Keshava".

Therefore the explanation and interpolation is not in the original text - both Shiva and Vishnu are forms of the same Supreme Being and He manifests Himself as Shankara (Shiva) Narayana (Vishnu).

Comment: Cite sources for your assertions. Unsourced answers might get deleted. Sources are mandatory on this site.

Comment: The Srimad bhagavad Mahapurana edition of Gita Press Gorakhpur has described the vidhi of Bhagavad Parayana as well as Bhagavad Sapthaham. Please refer to the same in the Introduction to the edition.

Comment: Smarthas are not shaivites.

Comment: Clear devatha taratamya is established. brahma sutra states Lord Narayana is the supreme being. nobody else should be compared or taught they will be equal once they reach moksha.. There is no difference between lord and his guna, if some sampradaya says that we would be equal in one or more gunas to the lord Narayana means estentially its same interpolation of advaita.. Even this should be condemened I solute the supreme being Narayana and supreme in jiva atma i.e. madha aka bhema aka hanuma.. in bring about this value in our tradition

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the curse is affecting only those who indulge in the blaspheming, who indulge in the beliefs and practices that are anti Vedic. This is seen from the text, [Bhagavatam canto 4, chapter 2](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/2):

> SB 4.2.30 — Bhṛgu Muni continued: **Since you blaspheme the Vedas and
>   the brāhmaṇas, who are followers of the Vedic principles**, it is
>   understood that **you have already taken shelter of the doctrine of
>   atheism**.
>   SB 4.2.31 — **The Vedas give the eternal regulative principles
>   for auspicious advancement** in human civilization which have been
>   rigidly followed in the past. The strong evidence of this principle is
>   the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who is called Janārdana, the
>   well-wisher of all living entities.
>   SB 4.2.32 — **By blaspheming the
>   principles of the Vedas**, which are the pure and supreme path of the
>   saintly persons, **certainly you followers of Bhūtapati, Lord Śiva, will
>   descend to the standard of atheism without a doubt**.

It doesn't mean all the Shaivas will become heretics. However I'm amazed to see that many Hindus who read the Bhagavatam immediately responded that those verses are interpolation. This is certainly not an interpolation because there is no evidence for that, and the same is said in other scriptures as well. It is said in several scriptures that some followers of Lord Shiva will become heretics. It is even said that Lord Shiva had a job to compose some heretic scriptures with the purpose to delude some people. It seems that the Bhagavatam in the above verses indicates that thing.

The people who do not understand something, and who stumble upon some verses in the scripture that are contrary to their personal belief usually react in such a manner that they proclaim those verses to be an interpolation. That usually just show their ignorance.

Comment: It is even said that Lord Shiva had a job to compose some heretic scriptures with the purpose to delude some people. --- Even Vishnu does the same and even more... Do u not know of the 3 asura brothers (Tripurasura) and how Vishnu deluded them and about Buddha whose sole purpose of taking birth is to delude people?

Comment: " It is said in several scriptures that some followers of Lord Shiva will become heretics. It is even said that Lord Shiva had a job to compose some heretic scriptures with the purpose to delude some people" I think these are your opinions. What are other scriptures which say Shiva devotees become heretic? What are the Sanskrit words used?

Comment: "It is even said that Lord Shiva had a job to compose some heretic scriptures with the purpose to delude some people." - So how was your meeting with Lord Shiva? Say Hi to him from my side when you encounter him the next time.

Comment: @Rickross If your point is why Shiva is being talked about here, It is easy to guess the simple reason for it - because the question is about Shiva!

Comment: @brahmajijnasa you can see the discussion between murari gupta and damodar pandit about bhrgu's curse http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf page 290-294.

Comment: @RaRa Can you summarise the conversation for me?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Wherever the lingam is established and worshipped with a conception that Shri Shiva and Shri Hari have separate parties, there Bhgu's curse will act, because of this offense of a dualistic concept.Hari and Shankara have one interest. If in the presence of a Shiva lingam someone worships Them without a dualistic concept, the curse will not have effect.   You can read yourself read completel. it has just 21 verses. https://nitaaiveda.com/Compiled_and_Imp_Scriptures/Krishna_Chaitanya_Charita_Mahakavya/Prakrama_3/Sarga9.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Some differences need to be understood and appreciated. (Ref: Tamil book, 'Deivathin Kural' (meaning 'Voice of God') compiled from the speeches of Kanchi Sankaracharyar.)

With respect to Veda, there are two types of religions: which accept Veda ('vaideeha' religion) and those which do not. The best example for the latter is Buddhism.

According to Veda (not to create any controversy, let me rephrase it as: according to several veda interpreters), Vishnu is the primary God. He is the real 'purusha'. (It may be interesting to note that Purusha Suktha, praising Lord Vishnu occurs in all the four Vedas.)

Not all Shiva worshipers avoid Vishnu. For example, Smarthas are called so since they live according to 'smrithi'. They worship both Vishnu and Siva. In fact, Sankaracharya of Kanchi signs as 'Narayana Smrithi'.

The ones who do not accept Vishnu but are only the followers of Siva are called 'Saivites'.

For Vishnu followers, Siva is accepted as the first Vaishnavite or Bhaghavatha. And Vaishnavism (Vishnu-followers) demands that all Vaishnavites should worship the 'bhhghavathas' more than 'bhaghavan'.

So, coming back to the question. the real intent of the saying should be that whoever accepts Veda have to accept Vishnu.

Comment: Hello, please add the reference  that supports your annwer.

Comment: Done. Thank you very much.