# Which scripture wrote the "Ganapathi Moola Mantra"?

Tags: scripture, mantras, ganesha

For removal of Drishti the remover should wash his/her hands and legs before entering the home and we believe Mantra can prevent Dhristi Doshas.

The following Mantra to prevent Dristi Doshas/ Evil eye:

**Ganapathi Moola Mantra:**

> Aum shreem hreem kleem glaum gum ganapathaye
>
> Vara-varadha sarva janam-mey vasamaanaya swaha

My question: Which scripture wrote/named "Ganapathi Moola Mantra"? (the one we used to remove obstacles) and what is the meaning of Ganapathi Moola Mantra?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It occurs in [this chapter](http://gdurl.com/fBkM) of the Narada Purana:

> **The immutable, the consort of Vishnu, the wife of Shambhu, minaketana, smriti, mamsa adorned with indu with manu and with the moon in the crest, Ganapati in the dative, then at the end vara veranda be added, then at the end of sarva one should utter janam, then add me vasham anaya bring them all to my control. The mantra ends in vahnipriya "svaha" wit twenty-eight letters.** Its sage is Ganaka, the metre nivrit Gayatri etc., the presiding deity is ganesha. The Bija is six shaktis beginning with "a" and the application of it is for the proportion of Mahaganapati.

I discuss Ganaka in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8059/36).  In any case, the part in bold may seem like gobbledygook, but that's because it's in code.  When decoded, here's what it looks like:

> Om Shrim hrim klim glaum Ganapataye Vara Varada sarvajanam me vashamanaya svaha

Answer (score 5):

Apart from being present in the NArada PurAna, the mantra is also present in many Agama scriptures. For example, in **Ganesha Vimarshini Tantram, Brihat Srikrama Tantram, ViswasAra Tantram** etc. In this answer i am quoting the verses from the Viswa SAra.

The Rishi, Chandah etc of the mantra is given in the Viniyoga verses as follows:

> Asya Sri MaHaganapati mahamantrasya Ganaka Rishih, Nibrt Gayatri
>   Chandaha, Mahaganapatir Devata...
>
> ............
>
> For the great mantra of MahAganapati, seer is Ganaka, meter is Nibrit
>   GAyatri, Deity is MahAganapati...

In Agamas, usually the mantras are always given in a hidden code and never mentioned in a direct manner. In this case, the mantra uddhAra verses (which when decoded gives the actual mantra) are as follows:

> Sri saktismaravubhivighnabijAni prathamam likhet| Yenantam ganapatim
>   paschAdwarAnte varadam padam | uktvA sarvajanam....
>
> ............
>
> First write the Sri beejam (Srim), then Shatki  (Hrim), then Smara
>   (Klim; also known as KAma beejam),then Vighna (Glaum) beejas followed
>   by the Ganapati (Gam)...

The mantra thus obtained is (without the OM at the beginning) :

> shrim hrim klim glaum gam ganapathaye
>
> Vara-varadha sarva janam-mey vasamaanaya swaha

and, which is known as the 28-lettered MahAmantra of Lord Ganesha (AshtAvimsatyakshara Ganapati mahAmantra).

And, for the mantra purascharana the total number of japa required is 4 lakh and 44 thousand.

> Asya purascharanajapaschatuschattvArimsatchttvArimsatsahsrakam.