# Can evil eyes affect innocents?

Tags: karma, evil

Can evil eyes/black magic affect both children, adults with spiritual devotional dharmic peaceful innocent absolutely righteous, never did any adharmic deeds to not a single sentient living being,in entire life, wise healthy pure-hearted, filled with pure energy, Kundalini flowing, protected by inner aura  void of any negative karma from birth, who'd never wish or do bad to any innocents or good people? Also how to cast off, prevent harmful malice, evil spirits, eyes, black magic?

Comment: these are just village concepts, marginal to mainstream Hinduism.  people still believe in them and practitioners can never be held to account for their "cures"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which scripture wrote the "Ganapathi Moola Mantra"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19775/which-scripture-wrote-the-ganapathi-moola-mantra)

Comment: 1. Yes 2. There are ways to cast off the evil eye starting from usage of salt to homams. You can also approach a highly-energetic being(as in someone with great spiritual power) to use their energy against the negative energy that is bothering you 3. There are ways to prevent it including chanting raksha stotrams, increasing your own spiritual power, increasing your own energy and containing it without throwing it around. Continuously chanting God's name such as rama nama japa is one of the easiest and most effective ways to ward off evil.

Comment: Like Shri Rama Raksha Stotra?

Comment: Yes. Like Rama Raksha Stotra.

Comment: If I know correctly, evil frequency invade through your forehead, so if I cover half of my forehead with hair, like majority of Japanese do (males cover nearly half, females cover 90% of forehead), would it also give more resistance?