# Lord Krishna is the only supreme God in the Srimad Bhagavatam but in the Vedas Lord Narayana is supreme. Why?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, gods

Lord Krishna is only supreme God in Bhagavatam, but Lord Narayana is supreme in the Vedas. Why? Is Lord Krishna only supreme God and not Lord Narayana?

Comment: Do you want to ask is Lord Krishna supreme or Lord vishnu?

Comment: Please tell supreme Lord out of Krishna and narayana.

Comment: it's according to diffearent beliefs.vashnavites belive vishnu/Narayana is supreme,gaudiya vaishnavites belive Lord Krishna is supreme but if we go by scriptures in earlier texts In rig Veda,Tattireya aryanaka Lord Vishnu is supreme while in Brahma samhita Lord Krishna is shown supreme while earlier he was considered Incarnation of Lord Vishnu and in Bhagavad Gita it is Brahman saying In the form of shri krishna

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Vishnu the incarnation of Krishna or the other way around, according to the Geetha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20688/3500)

Comment: This is primarily opinion based question. Gaudiyas say Krishna is Supreme while Vaishnavas say Narayana is Supreme.

Comment: What's the difference between Krishna or Vishnu? Did you find any? They both are same person. Whether you say Krishna is supreme or Vishnu is, in any case you will be referring same Lord.

Comment: Should I drink water or should I drink H2O? Which between water and H2O quenches thrust? Please someone suggest me. I am totally confused

Comment: Krishna and Vishnu are name of a single Supreme Personality. If you read Scriptures then you will find Vishnu is frequently addressed as VaasuDeva. There us no difference in the two. It is like asking the question I asked in above comment. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Both names refer to the same Divine Person. In the *Mahanarayana Upanishad* 1.29 it says (Swami Vimalananda translator):

> May we know Narayana. For that, may we meditate on Vasudeva. May Visnu impel us towards it.

and Vimalananda's commentary on this verse:

> the Highest Person here is supplicated as Narayana, Vasudeva, and Visnu. Until and unless He impels the individual Soul, it cannot contemplate Him, and without contemplation on Him, His true nature cannot be understood. the etymological meanings of the three epithets, are given at length in the *bhasyas* on the *Gita* and *Visnusahasranama*. Bhattabhaskara's explanation of these words in the Visnugayatri is noteworthy. He derives *Narayana* thus: The term Nara, being derived from the root *nr* to lead, means the leader of all creation. Nara derived from the above word denotes his offsprings. Narayana therefore, is the effective cause of all creatures. Thus Narayana is Paramatman. He is called Vasudeva in his immanent aspect, i.e., dwelling in all creatures as Antaryamin. The term Visnu implies His all-pervasiveness.

"various are Thy names, O Lord, in each and every name Thy power resides..." - Sri Chaitanya