# Is Krishna the source of Vishnu or other way round?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana

What Bhagavata Purana text mentions apropos this question? Is Bhagavan Krishna the source of all incarnations or Bhagavan Vishnu as traditionally believed?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20688/is-vishnu-the-incarnation-of-krishna-or-the-other-way-around-according-to-the-g

Answer (score 3):

> एतौ भगवतः साक्षात् हरेर्नारायणस्य हि ।  अवतीर्णाविहांशेन वसुदेवस्य
> वेश्मनि ॥ Bhagavatam 10.43.23 ॥
>
> Meaning: *These two brothers are Avataras of rays of the almighty Hari whose Abode is cosmic waters, descended on the earth in the home of
> Vasudeva.*
>
> अप्यद्य विष्णोर्मनुजत्वमीयुषो  भारावताराय भुवो निजेच्छया ।Bhagavatam
> 10.38.10
>
> Meaning: *..Lord Viṣṇu, the Abode of beauty and excellence, who by His own will
> has incarnated as a human being (Krishna) for lightening the burden of the earth.*
>
> प्रधानपुरुषावाद्यौ जगद्धेतू जगत्पती ।  अवतीर्णौ जगत्यर्थे स्वांशेन
> बलकेशवौ ॥ ३२ ॥
>
> Meaning: *They (Purusha and Prakriti) had descended on the earth in their Amshas as Balarama and Krishna for the good of the world.*

[Bhagavata Purana 10.43.23](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n1535/mode/1up)

[Bhagavata Purana 10.38.10](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n1504/mode/1up)

[Bhagavata Purana 10.38.32](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n1507/mode/1up)

Comment: Is the last verse from the Vishnu Purana?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury No, it's from the same chapter - 38th chapter of 10th canto

Comment: @TheDestroyer Why my answer is put on hold?

Comment: It is an opinion-based question. See this for details: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury It's perspective as most of things are. I've given the sources. And I can accept different opinions to my question. I thought that's how this works.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury And then why another question was not put on hold https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20688/6990

Comment: Ask @KeshavSrinivasan. Since, he closed your question.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury He claims that answers to this questions will tend to be based on references, which I believe, is not correct.Ive given the proper references. I need to speak to other moderator.

Comment: Ask him on chat.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury how to do that? Who to ask?

Comment: In the chatrooms. Vedanta & Philosophy or Hinduism rooms.

Comment: What about 1.9.10, 1.9.20, 2.5.12 ?