# Is the formless Krishna supreme?

Tags: krishna, brahman

I was told by an elder that according to the oldest Purana, the formless Krishna is supreme and he created the Trinity. He is not that Krishna who is lord Vishnu's avatar and all the other gods including the tridev and tridevis are Vaishnav and worship him also. There are no mantras or way to worship him. There are many explanations for creation of this universe but which one is true?

Comment: There are many explanations for creation of this universe but which one is true? - This will lead to opinions of users which is not allowed in this site as per regulations of this site!

Comment: @Akshay S actually it is allowed by just giving the information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Krishna the source of Vishnu or other way round?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22095/is-krishna-the-source-of-vishnu-or-other-way-round)

Comment: Other related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20688/12304 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30209/12304 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45303/12304