# Which are the 10 Mahapuranas dedicated to Shiva according to Skanda Mahapurana?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, shaivism

The largest Mahapurana, Skanda Purana of Shaiva sect in Kedara Khanda 1 says:

> **अष्टादशपुराणेषु दशभिर्गीयते शिवः। चतुर्भिर्भगवान् ब्रह्मा द्वाभ्यां देवी तथा हरिः॥** or ‘अठारह पुराणों में दस में शिव-स्तुति है, चार में ब्रह्मा की और दो में देवी तथा हरि की है।’

> Which means *out of the 18 Mahapuranas there are **10 of Shiva**, 4 of Brahma, 2 of Devi and Vishnu each.*

Vaishnavas and their Puranas classify 18 Mahapuranas with several dedicated to Vishnu and sometimes they do not consider Shiva Purana at all. So what are the lists of Shaivas? I heard of these:

1. Linga
2. Skanda
3. Shiva Rahasya
4. Shiva Dharma
5. Shiva
6. Maheshwara
7. Bhairava
8. Shivadharma
9. Shivadharmottara
10. Vamana
11. Kurma
12. Vayu

I also know that Dattatreya Purana is very important for some Shaivas. Can you please give some lists in Shaiva or Shakta Puranas, and by these sects?

Comment: In kedara kanda which chapter

Comment: Please mention the adhyāya no from Kedāra khaṇḍa too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chapter 2](https://archive.org/details/SriSkandaPuranam-SankaraSamhitaPart2/page/n9/mode/2up) of Sankara Samhita of Skandha Purana lists the name of 10 Shaiva Puranas as:

> तत्र शैवानि शैवं च भविष्यश्च द्विजोत्तमा:।
>
> मार्कण्डेयं तथा लैङ्गं वाराहं स्कान्दमेव च ।।
>
> मात्स्यमन्यत्तथा कौर्मे वामनं च मुनीश्वरा:।
>
> ब्रह्माण्डं च दशेमानि त्रीणि लक्षाणि संख्यया।। 31
>
> The Shaiva Puranas are Shiva Purana, Bhavisya Purana, Markandeya Purana, Linga Purana, Varaha Purana, Skandha Purana, Matsya Purana, Kurma Purana, Vamana Purana and Brahmanda Purana making count of ten.