# What are the two Mahapuranas which dedicated to goddess mentioned in Skanda purana

Tags: devi, skanda-purana

I heard there 10 puranas for shiva and 2 puranas for goddess  mentioned in skanda purana. What are the two puranas dedicated to goddess.

Comment: Linked: [Which are the ten Mahapuranas dedicated to Lord Shiva as per the Skanda Purāṇa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40985/which-are-the-10-mahapuranas-dedicated-to-shiva-according-to-skanda-mahapurana/46390#46390)