# What is the structure of Skanda Purana?

Tags: skanda-purana

How are the slokas in Skanda Purana divided?

Suppose Ramayana is divided into Kandas, which are further divided into sargas etc..

Comment: Have a look here too: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/what-is-the-correspondence-between-khandas-and-samhitas-in-the-skanda-purana/40498#40498. This is somewhat the original Skanda purana bifurcation. Not colonial bifurcation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Skanda Purana is divided into 7 Khandas viz: Maheswara Khanda, Vishnu Khanda, Brahma Khanda, Kasi Khanda, Avanthya Khanda, Nagara Khanda and Prabhasa Khanda.

Each of these Khandas is again sub-divided into various Upa-Khandas.

The [preface](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana1.html) part of the book "Essence of Skanda Purana" answers your query.

> Skanda (Kartika) Purana is the largest of all the major Eighteen
>   Puranas, divided into Seven ‘Khandas’ or Branches viz. Maheswara
>   Khanda, Vishnu Khanda, Brahma Khanda, Kasi Khanda, Avanthya Khanda,
>   Nagara Khanda and Prabhasa Khanda. Maheswara Khanda is subdivided into
>   three Upa Khandas as Kedara, Kaumarika and Arunachala. Vishnu Khanda
>   has nine Upa Khandas, viz. Venkatachala Mahatmya, Purushottama Kshetra
>   Mahatmya, Badarikashrama Mahatmya, Kartika Masa Mahatmya, Margasira
>   Masa Mahatmya, Vishakha Mahatmya and Ayodhya Mahatmya. Brahma Khanda
>   has three Upa Khandas viz. Sethu Mahatmya, Dharmaranya and Uttara /
>   Brahmottara. Kasi Khanda has two parts viz. Purvardha and Uttarardha.
>   Avanthya Khanda has three Upa Khandas viz. Avanti Kshetra Mahatmya,
>   Chaturasiti Linga Mahatmya and Reva Upa Khanda. Nagara Khanda has
>   Tirtha Mahatmya. Finally, Prabhasa Khanda has Prabhasa Kshetra
>   Mahatmya and Dwaraka Kshetra Mahatmya. The division of the Skanda
>   (Kartika) Purana into the Seven Khandas is to provide road-map
>   assistance to the readers.