# Lord Shiva as Adi Yogi taught Yoga to seven sages and in turn these seven sages spread across the world. Is this theory a new look to our mythology?

Tags: shiva, yoga, yogi, rishi

Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev is well known for his Isha Foundation and his yogic practices.

He came up with a theory, a seemingly new one regarding Lord Shiva and the origin of yoga in India.

**According to him**:

> "When we say “Shiva,” there are two fundamental aspects that we
>   are referring to. The word “Shiva” literally means “that which is not.”
>   On another level, when we say “Shiva,” we are referring to a certain
>   yogi, the Adiyogi or the first yogi, and also the Adi Guru, the first Guru,
>   who is the basis of what we know as the yogic science today.
>
> In the yogic culture, Shiva is not seen as a God. He was a being
>   who walked this land and lived in the Himalayan region. As the very
>   source of the yogic traditions, his contribution in the making of human
>   consciousness is too phenomenal to be ignored. This predates all
>   religion.

**Dawn of Yoga**:

> Over 15,000 years ago, Adiyogi appeared in the upper regions of the
>   Himalayas. No one knew where he came from or what his origins
>   were. He just came and went into intense ecstatic dance upon the
>   mountains.
>
> People saw that he was experiencing something that nobody had known before, something that they were unable to fathom. So they gathered around him wanting to know what it was. But no one had the courage to go near him because he was so intense, like a blazing flame of fire. So they waited, hoping something would happen. Some people waited for months and left and Only seven hardcore seekers stuck on. These seven were insistent that they must learn from him, but Shiva ignored them. They pleaded and begged him, “Please, we want to know what you know.”
>
> At last after 84 years of intense sadhana,he decided to become a Guru. On a  full moon day which is known as Guru Pournami because the Adiyogi transformed himself into the Adi Guru – the first Guru was born on that day. He took the seven disciples to Kantisarovar and started a systematic exposition of yoga in a scientific manner. He began propounding the whole mechanics of life to these seven people, not intellectually as a philosophy, but experientially. He  explored every nut and bolt of creation with them. He brought forth yoga as a technology with which every human being can evolve himself.
>
> The transmission went on for a long period of time. After many years, when it was complete and had produced seven fully enlightened beings, who are today
>   celebrated as the Sapta Rishis, Adiyogi sent each one of them to different parts of the world. One went to Central Asia. Another went to North Africa and the Middle East, where certain schools exist even today. Another went to South America, and that is one culture that imbibed it in a deep way and made  something big out of it. One went to East Asia.
>
> One stayed right there with Adiyogi. Another one came to the lower regions of the Himalayas and started what is known as Kashmiri Shaivism. Another one went south into the Indian Peninsula. This one is very important for us because he is Agastya Muni. Of the seven Sapta Rishis, Agastya Muni has been the most effective in terms of bringing the spiritual process into practical life, not as a teaching, philosophy or a practice, but as life itself. It is the benefit of what he did that the Indian people are still enjoying because he produced hundreds of yogis who were like fireballs." and it goes on.

This is a new look at the beginning of Yogic tradition in India.

**What is the basis for this story? Was it taken from some Purana or was it an oral tradition?**

Is this a true one or a speculated theory?

If it's a speculated then it adds to more confusion caused by the Puranas.

Comment: THere is no basis to this theory. Everything about this- the meaning of the word Shiva, the really short timeline for the establishment of the guru relative to the age of the universe , to name two are all wrong. Most things that this so-called guru says are incorrect wrt theory and scripture.

Comment: @moonstar2001 please do scriptural analysis before rejecting in the very first instance. This story is projected by Govt. of India for the 1st ever launch of International day of yoga and it could be found in the Minsitry of external affairs website. http://www.mea.gov.in/in-focus-article.htm?25096/Yoga+Its+Origin+History+and+Development

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR I've made some edits to use blockquotes. I wasn't sure if you just copied some stuff from [this article](http://isha.sadhguru.org/blog/yoga-meditation/demystifying-yoga/classical-yoga-an-introduction-to-the-origin-of-yoga/) or re-wrote the above in your own words. When you quote someone, it's better to add links or references to the original article or blog.

Comment: @sv. thanx it was sourced from one of e-books of Isha foundation. i asked  it as the same story also appeared in the Ministry of External Affairs, GOI article Yoga its origin history and development by Director of Morarji Desai National Institute of Yoga.(which is an institute of international importance by GOI).

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR Also, unless it's copyrighted you should add a link to the e-book, in your question.

Comment: GOI, MEA and international yoga day are rooted in scripture? I know enough scripture to know this is incorrect, I have also seen enough Jaggi's interviews to conclude he does not know scripture.

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR I have been watching a sadguru videos for a long time, he seems to know something beyond physical, however he always confuses .. ;) regarding shiva what I have read is that it was just an **"Title"** means there were many shivas.

Comment: Yes @Rishi there are two types of Jnana one is paurusha another is baudhik. He has Paurush jnana as he has experienced something non physical but he has no baudhik jnana. Btw, many here on SE has later one jnana.

Comment: @Seeker you mean "भौतिक" ?, Okay got it and you are right we do not understand other dimension

Comment: @Rishi बौद्धिक।

Comment: @Rishi - Shiva and Narayana are not titles. Shiva is eternal and singular.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Shiva was a Title, But the one with parvati and Ganesha was at the time of Ramayana.

Comment: @Rishi   Nope. Wrong.

Comment: @user1195 can you be more clear as to which aspect of the above question did you deem that someone doesn't know scripture and somehow you have excelled in it? Please be very specific as to the content and the context. Like for example "I am not inclided to Shiva being addressed Adi Yoga and want Scriptural evidence to it?" Also please share the Vedic Shaka you belong to and the scriptural school you have completed. Thank you.

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR Its not just Sadhguru, other researchers also had the same conclusion. Many people under deep affection towards Puranic literature are stuck with exuberant numbers that go in millions. Here is a very good research video on Yoga and its origin, https://youtu.be/JoRwXMLsVis. 
Also, there are many people with textbook knowledge who dislike Sadhguru and they don't care no matter how much good he does to the nation and Youth who are moving away from his cultural roots. Sadhguru doesn't operate on echoing what textbooks say. He goes by personal experience, Good day.

Answer (score 4):

The Dakshinamurthy is the adiyogi. His idol is there in all south indian temples facing south.

See this wiki article [Dakshinamurthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakshinamurthy)

It is not new and is there in yogic tradition.But the fact is that the traces of the pure yogic tradition and its essence is more or less destroyed in the north india after years of long invavsion. But the south particularly tamilnadu was free from severe invasion of outsiders.

see this pic with seven sages in one of the old indian temples in madurai.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You can cite authentic Scriptures such as Puranas for your sentence "Dakshinamurty is Adi Yogi " and you can explain it detail.

Comment: @TheDestroyer . Hinduism is the only religion or culture that doesnt go by scriptures. It is through inner experience always. I didnt read enough scriptures to answer your query and shiva is older than all the scriptures. you can see the pashupathi seal in the indus valley.

Comment: No. Scriptures make answers more authentic. So, this site lays more emphasis for sources. You can visit [this question](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/786/can-we-revisit-the-sources-required-rule).

Comment: @TheDestroyer..http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/what-scriptures-mention-shivas-dakshinamurthi-form

Comment: While Scriptures are an important source of confirmation - in Sanatana Dharma we do not have authorized versions of our religious scriptures.  Various scholars give varying interpretations.  The interpretation of Jaggi Vasudeva is one amongst many.  Shiva undoubtedly was the Jagat Guru / Adi Guru - teacher of the world / first teacher. In Valmiki Ramayana Mahatmiyam expounded in Uttara Khanda of Skanda Purana there is reference to this in Naradas dialouge with Sanat Kumaras. आस्ते कृतयुगे विप्रो धर्मकर्मविशारदः || सोमदत्त इति ख्यातो नाम्ना धर्मपरायणः |

Comment: विप्रस्तु गौतमाख्येन मुनिना ब्रह्मवादिना || श्रावितः सर्वधर्माश्च गङ्गातीरे मनोरमे |
पुराणशास्त्रकथनैस्तेनासौ बोधितोऽपि च || श्रुतवान् सर्वधर्मान् वै तेनोक्तानखिलनापि |
कदाचित् परमेशस्य परिचर्यापरोभवत् || उपस्थितायापितस्मै प्रणामं न् चकार स: |
स तु शान्तो महाबुद्धिर्गौतमस्तेजसां निधिः  शास्त्रोदितानि कर्माणि करोति स मुदं ययौ | यस्त्वर्चितो महादेवः शिवः सर्व जगद्गुरुः | र्ववज्ञाकृतम् पापं राक्षसत्वे नियुक्तवान् |

[Skanda Purana UttaraKhanda Srimad Valmiki Mahatmyam 2:29 - 35]

Comment: The story in Skanda Purana is about a brahmin somadutta who learnt the scriptures at the feet of Maharishi Gautama.  One day he was worshiping Lord Shiva when Gautama came to him.  So engrossed was he in the worship he did not notice his guru and ignored hm.  Maharishi Gautama with his divine insight knew of his disciple's engrossment that he did not mind the slight to him - but not the God he was worshipping.    यस्त्वर्चितो महादेवः शिवः सर्व जगद्गुरुः |गुर्ववज्ञाकृतम् पापं राक्षसत्वे नियुक्तवान् |  For the sin of ignoring his Guru Shiva cursed him to become a Raakshasa..

Comment: What was the knowledge imparted by the Jagat Guru. According to Shiva Purana His first disciples were the Sapta Rishis and to them He imparted the secrets of Yoga, the Creation, its Preservation and Destruction. This knowledge was imparted without any words being spoken.  Since the Secrets of Yoga were imparted by Him, He became the Adi Yogi or the First Yogi. Sadguru Jaggi Vasudeva's claim that he lived 15000 years ago in Himalayas is immaterial.  Whether He lived 15000 years ago or 15 million years ago He imparted the knowledge of Yoga to us.

Answer (score 1):

Sadhguru in many of his Satsangs told Adiyogi IS Dakshinamurthy 
He explained hat since Adiyogi sat facing South in Himalayas, people called him Dakshinamurthy.

The Devon ke Dev Maha dev tv series showing Shiva as Adiyogi ( Thats how Parvati calls him in one of her births ) teaching yoga to Parvati. This tv serial as they claim they have taken references from Shiva Purana.

Also i remember reading in Shivapurana that Shiva is Adiyogi.

Comment: The question is looking for the story. Also you should cite authentic sources. Tv serials [aren't](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/277) considered authentic source.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yes what Sadhguru says is true. He is talking about Dakshinamurthy version of Shiva.  Many Yogic traditions such as Babaji parampara ,Nath sampradaya , Aghoris and those who follow Dakshinamurthy with yogic perspective consider him as Adinath or Adiyogi.Its interesting how Jain's call their first Tirthankar as "Adinath".What's even more interesting is his name. Which is "Rishabnath" (Lord of bull). Take whatever yogic sampradaya/parampara. Their origin touches Adiyogi/Adinath Shiva. The story of Shiva being Adiyogi is also present on Shiva Rahasya Puran which is based on his teachings as Adiyogi. The text is based on Yoga. Do read it. It contains deepest secrets . The contents from that book is first yoga teachings ever it seems.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivarahasya_Purana

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> “He is Yoga and the Abode/Lord of Yoga” ~ Mahabharatam Drona Parva 203

So, as the very abode of Yoga and being the very YOGA himself, he is Adi Yogi, "The first yogi" who is one with creation.

Let's go further back into the Vedas:

> He is the one who brought forth the Seven Sages (saptarśi) as the
> Seven Gems RV6.74.1

As he was the foremost, they placed him on 'Dakshina' and so-called him Dakshina Murthi  ~SU4.21.

Many interpret the word dakshina as only “South”. In Sanskrit, dahkshina means “to be on the right side” or “correct/highest position”; another meaning is “that which is linked through Yajñá (sacrificial process)”. Hence, the word Pra:dakshina, meaning to circle around the deity towards our right, signifies the stature of the deity. Since He (Śiva) is medha-patim – “the resort of Yajñá/sacrifice” RV1.43 TS1.3.14 – and is seated at the top (pinnacle) of the Himalayan mountains with the daughter of the mountains, He overlooks everything below. Hence the title Dakshina Murthi. But is it that simple? How can one seek the identity and the source of Dakshina facing Rudra? One can seek Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad 4.21, which says “हे रुद्र यत् ते दक्षिणं मुखं तेन मां नित्यं पाहि॥”; here “Dakshina Mukham” does not mean facing South, it denotes the auspicious side of Him – with which He always protects. The term Highest Position does not mean just North or limited to one specific direction, because He is “dishām ca pataye” and “Pathīnāṃ-Pataye” TS4.5.2,VS16.17 – meaning the abode/lord of all celestial quarters (directions). Hence the famous title, digambara (Digeva:ambaram:asya) – meaning the one who is clad/clothed with space and all directions. Atharva Veda 11.2.14-16 says to Bhava-Rudra, “नमो यतमस्यां दिशीतः” – meaning, “our salutations to you in whatever directions you are” – and it continues by saying, “salutations to you while coming or going, while seated or standing, and while day or night”. This concept gave rise to the title Cidamabara, meaning the one clad with the very consciousness (cit), hence the Chidambaram Nataraja temple in Tamil Nadu, India.
Various Rishis scattered in various direction from the Land of Bharath and many Kshetras emerged in their Honor like The Sri Ananthavalli sametha Agastheeswarar Malai kovil temple which hold the Linga established by Rishi Agasthya in Chennai.

Rishi Kapila established Linga and that kshetra is called Kapileshwar Teertham in Tirupati Andhra Pradesh.

So those who traversed the land of Bharat will witness various Kshetras developed by various Rishis in honor of Lord Shiva and established Lingas.

**In the Sanatana Culture, the names are derivations of Actions and Attributes.** Rather than calling them names they are mostly adjectives and praises that soon become titles or acclamation. For example, the title Rudra is an acclamation of the tendencies of being ferocious. The same Rudra is Siva at times, hence they started calling him by a gentler title 'Siva'. So let's cover a few examples.

Since He had no name and came from the North (Mūjavant), and dwelled in mountains, they called him Girisha. And they called his abode in the mountains as Kailash ~RVB33 as this is where all the Devas dwell being delighted in his presence. He then married the daughter of the mountains who was called Parvati, meaning Parvata Raja Putri or Himavati. Kenopanishad says “Uma daughter of Himavat” they called him Umapathi ~TA10.22.40.22 .

All beings (bhootas) flocked around him, including pious, nefarious, and animals, especially snakes as they have unique chemistry with those in a meditative state, so they called him Paśūpati/Satpati/Bhootapati TS4.5.2, RV2.33.12, AV11.2.1 so as an overlord of all beings they called him Isha. Those who were brave and courageous took a step towards him and so He became the leader of the brave RV10.92.9.

He was independent and sovereign they called Svatantra, Svadhanva, and Svatava RV1.166.2 (Sva = sovereign).

Since he was the supreme overload/authority they called him Isha. So together he was titled Isha + Sva = Ishvar.

In him, they saw Mahat = the great principle, so they called him Maha + Isha + Svara = Mahesvara.

In him they saw Vishvam, they called him Vishveswara.

In him, they saw everything (Sarva) so they called him Sarveshwara ~CKA2.100.

They saw the highest Divinity in him so they called him Mahadeva ~SB6.3.

They realized he was foremost and pure so they called him Sriṣṭhaḥ. ~RV

In this way, the titles go on. Similarly, the Nath traditions called him Adi-Nath. Devi being the first to start a family they called her Adi-Kutumbhini.

In this way many traditions emerged from Vedic Rudra. There is also the Pashipati clans. From Vrātyas RV3.26,5.53,AV15, came many nomadic sages or wanderers that gave raise to Aghora sects.

[Source](https://namahshivaya.net/rudra-siva-maha-mrityunjaya-mantra-for-liberation/)