# What are the contributions of all seven disciples of Adiyogi?

Tags: yoga

Please explain the contributions of all seven disciples of Adiyogi and what were their identity in western world . Kindly answer with available proofs.

Comment: This question seems to have no relation with the Sanatana Dharma that is based on scriptures

Comment: @Partha Why do you think so ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto i never found the reference of this. Even the adiyogi name is new to me.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/lord-shiva-as-adi-yogi-taught-yoga-to-seven-sages-and-in-turn-these-seven-sages?rq=1