# Why is dakshina murthy suppressing the demon Apasmara and what is his story?

Tags: shiva

Lord Dakshina Murthi, is considered as the source of all types of knowledge. This form represents Shiva as a teacher of yoga, music, wisdom and giving exposition on the shastras. He is worshipped as the god of wisdom, complete and rewarding meditation. The significance of Dakshina murthy is explained in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/what-scriptures-mention-shivas-dakshinamurthi-form/13945#13945)

[image: Dakshina murthy]

He is seen suppressing a demon [Apasmara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apasmara) with his foot.

The relation between Apasmara and Shiva is not only limited to Dakshina Murthy but with other forms like Nataraja and Shiva in his human form. There is a temple by the name [Parashurameshwara Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudimallam) situated in Gudimallam, Andhra Pradesh. In this temple, Lord Shiva is shown as suppressing demon Apasmara.

**Questions:**

- What is the story of the demon Apasmara, Daskshina murthy is suppressing with his foot?

Comment: I think that lil demon represents ignorance..That's why Shiva being "knowledge without limit" keeps him suppressed...because knowledge and ignorance/illusion can not co exist..

Comment: @Rickross Yes. I thought there would be a story for that . You can see him under the feet of Nataraja too.

Comment: Yes there must be some story told in some puranas..

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am looking for the story from scriptures.