# Mantra, Stotras on Nataraja, Dakshinamurty?

Tags: scripture, shiva, mantras, stotra

Is There Any Mantra, Stotra, Sukta..etc..anything related to Nataraja, Dakshinamurty..etc..especially connected to Apasmara..

What is the story, Is Apasmara under Dakshinamurty OR Nataraja...Want to read detailed story..

Answer (score 5):

There are Stotras for both Lord Dakshinamurty and Nataraja.

There is the famous [Dakshinamurty Stotra authored by Adi Shankaracharya](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/dakshinamurthy_stotram.php).

> मौनव्याख्या प्रकटित परब्रह्मतत्त्वं युवानं
>  वर्षिष्ठांते वसद्
> ऋषिगणैः आवृतं ब्रह्मनिष्ठैः ।
>  आचार्येन्द्रं करकलित
> चिन्मुद्रमानंदमूर्तिं
>  स्वात्मारामं मुदितवदनं दक्षिणामूर्तिमीडे ॥१॥
>
> Mauna-Vyaakhyaa Prakattita Para-Brahma-Tattvam Yuvaanam
> Varssisstthaam-Te Vasad Rssigannaih Aavrtam Brahma-Nisstthaih |
> Aacaarye[a-I]ndram Kara-Kalita Cin-Mudram-Aananda-Muurtim
> Sva-[A]atmaaraamam Mudita-Vadanam Dakssinnaamuurti-Miidde ||1||
>
> Meaning: 1: (Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy) Whose Exposition
> through Profound Silence is Awakening the Knowledge of the Supreme
> Brahman in the Hearts of His Disciples; Who is Himself Youthful ... 2:
> ... but is Sitting Surrounded by Old and Great Sages who are Devoted
> to Brahman, 3: The Hands of the Supreme Spiritual Teacher is Forming
> the Cin-Mudra (gesture of the Knowledge of Brahman) and Whose
> Appearance is Still and Blissful, 4: Who is Rejoicing in His Own Self
> which is reflected on His Blissful Face; Salutations to Sri
> Dakshinamurthy.

This is the first verse from the Stotra. The verse no. 4 (given blow) is widely used as a Guru Shloka by those who don't yet have a Guru of their own.

> निधये सर्वविद्यानां भिषजे भवरोगिणाम् ।
>  गुरवे सर्वलोकानां
> दक्षिणामूर्तये नमः ॥४॥
>
> Nidhaye Sarva-Vidyaanaam Bhissaje Bhava-Roginnaam |
>  Gurave
> Sarva-Lokaanaam Dakssinnaamuurtaye Namah ||4||
>
> Meaning:
> 4.1: (Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy) Who is a receptacle to all Knowledge, Who is a Medicine to all the diseases of Worldly bondage,
>
> 4.2: Who is a Guru to all the Worlds; Salutations to Sri Dakshinamurthy.

And, for Nataraja swarupa of Lord Shiva, there is Patanjali Krita Nataraja Stotra.
You can get it from either [here](https://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Script/147/nataraj-stotra) or [here (without translation)](https://stotranidhi.com/en/sri-nataraja-stotram-patanjali-krutam-in-english/).

> sadaJNchita mudaJNchita nikuJNchita padaM jhalajhalaJNchalita maJNju
> kaTakam.h
>  pataJNjali dR^igaJNjana manaJNjana machaJNchalapadaM
> janana bhaJNjana karam.h |
>  kadambaruchimambaravasaM paramambuda
> kadamba kaviDambaka kagalam.h
>  chidambudhi maNiM budha hR^idambuja
> raviM para chidambara naTaM hR^idi bhaja || 1||
>
> Heartily resort to the great dancer Shiva, residing in the holy place,
> Chidambaram. He is called Hara (the destroyer) who smashed the three
> cities (of demon tripura). He is worshipped by good people. While
> dancing he has lifted one foot which is bent. His lovely bracelets are
> set in motion of dance movements and hence are making a jingling
> sound. He is like ointment to the eyes of Patanjali by whose
> application the vision gets clear for receiving knowledge. However, he
> is free from contamination of any kind. He destroys the cycle of birth
> (and death). He possesses the loveliness of Kadamba tree; wears the
> sky as garment . His throat is dark like the multitude of rainy
> clouds. He is the jewel in the ocean of consciousness. He is the the
> Sun blossoming the lotus- heart of wise persons.
>
> haraM tripura bhaJNjanaM anantakR^itakaN^kaNaM akhaNDadaya
> mantarahitaM
>  viriJNchisurasaMhatipurandhara vichintitapadaM
> taruNachandramakuTam.h |
>  paraM pada vikhaNDitayamaM bhasita
> maNDitatanuM madanavaJNchana paraM
>  chirantanamamuM
> praNavasaJNchitanidhiM para chidambara naTaM hR^idi bhaja || 2||
>
> Heartily resort to the great dancer, Shiva, residing in the holy
> place, Chidambaram. He is the destroyer of the world, who destroys sin
> and grants emancipation. He has destroyed the three cities of demon
> tripura, representing the three types of sorrows. He is wearing the
> great serpent, ananta, like a bracelet. He is incessantly showering
> compassion and is endless. "God Brahma, Indra and the other devatas
> meditate upon his feet. The crescent moon adorns his crown."
>
> The great one has crushed yama by his feet. His body is decorated with
> ash. He is inclined to brush aside cupid. His preciousness is
> saturated in the syllable - AUM.

Nataraja is the presiding deity of [the Chidambaram temple of Tamil Nadu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nataraja_Temple,_Chidambaram), India. There is also one Stotra dedicated to [Lord Nataraja/Chidambareswara](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Chidambareswara_Stotram).

The author of this Stotra is not known. Here is the first verse of the Stotra:

> Krupa samaudram, sumukham, trinethram,
>  Jadadaharam, Parvathi vama
> bhagam,
>  Sada shivam, rudramanantha roopam,
>  Chidambaresam
> hrudhi bhavayami., 1
>
> I meditate on that Lord of Chidambaram, Who is the ocean of mercy, Who
> has a pleasant mien, Who has three eyes, Who has matted locks, Who
> keeps Parvathy on his left side, Who is ever peaceful, And who is
> limitless and angry.

And, for the story of Nataraja and the demon Apasmara, there is already a question: [Why is dakshina murthy suppressing the demon Apasmara and what is his story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17330/why-is-dakshina-murthy-suppressing-the-demon-apasmara-and-what-is-his-story)

Comment: Hello..Hi..I have read So Many Answers of Yours..Legend..I had seen that Apasmara Q..but doesnt have any answer...

Comment: I read on Quora that..According to certain theory apasmara represent the five senses of the human nature. Nataraja dances in celestial ecstasy showing how man should control the senses..... So..I was trying to find Stotra related to Apasmara being supressed by Shiva..either in Dakshinamurty form OR Nataraja Form..

Comment: Apasmara is a demonic entity  that suppresses mental faculty like memory and only Nataraja can suppress it not Dakshinamurty. Dakshinamurty is Guru Swarupa @HinduKid

Comment: You can ping me here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80586/room-for-ram-and-rickross @HinduKid

Comment: I just did..No response..I also read a story that..Apasmara..small demon was disturbing the Meditation of 4Rishis..and they prayed to shive..shiva appeared in dakshinamurty form..and supressed the demon by putting under his feet..

Comment: That form is of Nataraja and not Dakshinamurty .. you can check the story again. @HinduKid You can also check any idol of Nataraja, you will find a small demon lying under one of his feet, that demon is Apasmara.

Comment: You Can See in this [Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17330/why-is-dakshina-murthy-suppressing-the-demon-apasmara-and-what-is-his-story) ..There are 4 rishis, and Shiva supressing demon..

Comment: Yes thanks .. I have not noticed that pic carefully earlier @HinduKid

Comment: @HinduKid Strangely I am having problems with opening the chatrooms. But otherwise I do not have problems .. for e.g. websites and other things are working well. I will catch you later in the chatroom.