# How did the Puranas justify the deification of epithets, which is contrary to Rig Vedic principles, therefore, anti-Hindu or anti-Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: puranas, rig-veda

Rig Veda [II.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02001.htm) states that there is only one Brahman, though attributed different epithets like *Indra*, *Vishnu*, *Rudra*, etc., to denote different actions of the same Almighty. The same was reiterated in [RV I.164.46](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01164.htm):

> एकं सद विप्रा बहुधा वदन्त्यग्निं
>
> ekaṃ sad viprā bahudhā vadantyaghniṃ
>
> Though it is One, inspired poets speak of it in many ways

The Puranas on the other hand eulogise Vishnu, Shiva, etc, by deification, and demean Indra, Agni, Aswins, etc,  even though according to Vedas, Indra, Agni, Aswins, etc, were  epithets much like *Vishnu* and *Rudra*.

Deification of epithets is anti-Hindu or anti-Sanatana Dharma.

So how did the Puranas like Vishnu Purana, Shiva Purana, etc, justify the deification of epithets, as mentioned above, and advocating sectarian movements like Vaishnavism, Shaivism, etc., which are contrary to Rig Vedic principles?

Comment: You can find that thing in Rigveda also - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19885/12304

Comment: I am asking for justification from Puranas @YDS

Comment: The same Rig Vedic verse I.164.46 says **ekaṃ sad viprā bahudhā vadantI**.  The epithets like Vishnu, Agni, Indra, etc, belong to same Almighty.  There is NO superiority or inferiority in Rig Veda.  The other answer you had quoted is a wrong answer @YDS

Comment: Even Puranas say that the Brahman is the ultimate reality https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23603/12304 but diff Puranas praise diff god as Brahman..it's same as RV where in some verse one god is praised as Brahman in another verse diff god..same is with MBH where Garuda, Agni, Indra and many other gods are praised as Brahman..

Comment: @YDS: You are getting confused here.  In Rig Veda, the same Almighty was eulogised in different epithets, but deification was not there.  Whereas, in Puranas, deification was very much evident, and denigration of deified gods like Indra, Agni, etc , was also very much evident.

Comment: Sorry, I see confusion in the vocabulary. "Deification" is very confusing and not appropriate. Every Deva is a deity. Indra, Agni, etc are all deities, so they have already been "deified". Calling them "epithets" is an Arya Samaj idea, not found in ancient tradition. Just because they are deities, does not make it harder to see their unity or equal status.

Comment: As far as I understood, those are epithets of the God.  I prefer to that line of thinking. By the way, I am not an Arya samaj follower :-) @RamAbloh

Comment: I am not against Puranas :- ) @RamAbloh . They are useful in early stages to keep oneself attached to Godly concepts, though not make Spiritual.  Even myself read Puranas during my childhood. However, denigrating some characters like Indra in order to elevate Vishnu or Shiva, etc,  is nothing but a marketing strategy, which I am not in favour of.

Comment: In order to make believe Sri Rama as incarnation of Vishnu, the scholars of later period inserted Disowning of Sita episode (Agni pravesha) in Ramayana.  This interpolation might have served their purpose, but finally led to presenting Sri Rama as a male chauvinist and his character assassination ) @RamAbloh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  epithets Indra, Rudra, Shiva, Vishnu, etc, are used to indicate the male aspects of same Almighty, in Rig Veda.

There is no deification of these epithets in Rig Veda.

---

The word Vishnu has etymological roots in viś, meaning to pervade, thereby connoting that Vishnu is "one who is everything and inside everything".

The story of Vamana, covering 3 areas in 3 steps, has roots in this eulogisation of the pervasiveness of Almighty God.

Interestingly, [Rig Veda IV.18.5](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04018.htm), describes that Indra filled, as soon as born, the earth and heaven.

So it is the pervasiveness of the God that denotes VISHNU.

---

Similarly, [Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40428/3869) indicates auspiciousness.

---

[Rig Veda II.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02001.htm) states that there is only one Brahman, though attributed different epithets like Indra, Vishnu, Rudra, etc., to denote different actions of the same Almighty. The same was reiterated in RV I.164.46, as indicated in the question content.

---

The female aspect of the Almighty (BRAHMAN) was described as [Saraswati](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv06061.htm),Ushas, etc, in Rig Veda.

---

However, due to decrease in the understanding capacity of the then people in India, these epithets were deified and Puranas were composed eulogising Vishnu, Shiva, etc, as **SUPREME gods**,  in respective Puranas like Vishnu Purana, Shiva Purana, etc.

The many achievements/ attributes of Indra were attributed to Vishnu or Shiva.  While doing so, the so many vices were attributed to the deified Indra, such as womaniser, greedy towards his seat, etc.

**It is not Sanatana Dharma**, as per Rig Veda.

Comment: I see you've given yourself a free green check mark. You should broaden your understanding on this topic (as should I).

Comment: It was my question and there was no satisfactory answer posted by any member. And,  none other than myself can accept my own answer.  :-).  Understand the technicalities before making comment on my understanding. @MassInquirer

Comment: @MassInquirer: You better  ask a question to the members, who opted for closing my question, without quoting any valid reason.  I know who there were, but the site rules and attitude of the biased moderator and reluctance on the part of the Help Centre to intervene when a request made earlier, made me accept my own answer.

Comment: so do you mean to say that puranas are not to studied or respected upon, common bhagavata purana is much worshipped in hinduism, as is markandeya purana (chandi path)!

Comment: I am not denying the importance of Puranas in the early stages of ONE's growth in SPIRITUAL realm.  Even I did **pArAyana** of Durga Saptasathi, Sundara Kanda, Guru Charitra many times.  I have gone through the EPICs and Puranas.   Even now Ramayana is my passion. Having said that I should say that as one matures, ONE should be prepared to move forward leaving behind the actions done in earlier stages.   For that matter even the Veda is not required,  when one gets SELF REALISATION.  Did Sri Ramana Maharshi read the Veda ? @vidyarthi