# Who founded "Pushti mArga" and how is it different than "Vaishnavism"?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, pushti-marga

Typically in Gujarat region of India, the devotees of [Shrinathji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji) follow "Pushti mArga". I would like to know:

- Who founded it & when?
- How is it different than conventional Vaishnavism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"Who founded it & when?"*

*Pushti mArga* is the sub-sect of [Rudra Sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rudra_Sampradaya&oldid=742268668). It was founded by [Vallabhacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pushtimarg&oldid=740952029) around 1500 AD.

> *"How is it different than conventional Vaishnavism?"*

I suppose by conventtional Vaishnavism you mean [Sri Vaishnavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sri_Vaishnavism&oldid=743425391). Main basic difference between Sri Vaishnavism and Pushti Marga is as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vaishnavism&oldid=741339961#Traditions):

- Lord Vishnu is supreme god in *Sri Vaishnava* sect while Shri Krishna is supreme god in *Pushti mArga*.
- [Vishishtadvaita](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vishishtadvaita&oldid=739151733) is the philosophy of Sri Vaishnava sect while [Shuddhadvaita](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shuddhadvaita&oldid=732105191) is the philosophy of *Pushti mArga*.

You can read more about this at [hindupedia.com](http://hindupedia.com/en/Vaishnava) and [Dvaita vs Advaita vs Vishistadvaita vs Shuddhadvaita vs any other](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/dvaita-vs-advaita-vs-vishistadvaita-vs-shuddhadvaita-vs-any-other).

Comment: Thanks, even I am also from "Pushti mArga" and I never knew that it believes in "Shuddhadvaita". How is it dereived from "Rudra sampradAya"? Isn't the "Rudra" more related to "Shaivism"?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Rudra Sampradaya is interesting, why didn't they name it Vishnu Sampradaya because according to their beliefs, Vishnu imparted the knowledge to Rudra and then Rudra to others so Vishnu came first.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I do not know the complete history but what I think is since Lord Shiva is believed to be the Guru who passed knowledge to others. So, the devotees/sages/siddha got knowledge from Shiva, not from Narayana. So, maybe they had named is as Rudra Sampradaya (knowledge by Rudra). Also, there is Brahma Sampradaya but again Vishnu is their god. So, IMO there should be some hidden meaning may be the nature of sect or something else.

Comment: @iammilind Please check the link http://www.harekrsna.com/philosophy/gss/sadhu/sampradayas/sampradayas.htm

Comment: Yes - Vallabhacharya. Good answer - including wikipedia links and also linking the related question that includes Shuddhadvaita also.

Comment: @iammilind Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11647/277